# signal() handler gets fired immediately

Tags: c, signals

Trying to implement process interruption handling using [this function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/signal.3.html).
Following code running on OS X 10.10:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sys/wait.h"

sig_t terminate(){
    printf("Thanks for the fish!\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    signal(SIGINT, terminate());
    while (1){
        printf("P");
    }    
}
```

Problem is, that the `terminate` function is called immediately after running the program. Means, one does not see a single `P`, but only a line of `Thanks for the fish!`.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass a function name instead of calling the function

```
signal(SIGINT, terminate );
```

Also signal takes the function pointer of type

```
void handler_function (int parameter);
```

Comment: Changed the `sig_t terminate(){` to `void terminate(){` along with this solution. Works now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your signal handler does not match required prototype. You should redefine `terminate()` to take an `int` as parameter and return `void`.

That is,

```
void terminate(int sig) {
    printf("Thanks for the fish!\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

// ...
signal(SIGINT, terminate);
```